# Android sqlite: get number of rows in a table?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to find the number of rows n a sqlite table using this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Gets the data repository in write mode
   SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("app_alldata",MODE_PRIVATE,null); 

   mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userinfo(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");

   Cursor cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userinfo;",null);

   int cnt = cursor.getCount();
  String letsee = Integer.toString(cnt);
   final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    textViewToChange.setText(letsee); 

   }
```

When I run the app, i always see the number "1" in the textview, even though I am sure that the row count is not 1.

what's wrong with my code?

Note: the app doesn't crash and I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 3):

your are getting the count of the cursor.
how many rows the cursor returned.

you should:

```
cursor.getInt(ColumnNameIndex);
```

also notice that you need to move to the first position of the cursor:

```
boolean isOk = cursor.moveToFirst()
int count = cursor.getInt(0)
```

Comment: I tried cursor.getInt(Username);, and now it says: "Username" cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: also for next time if you want to know which columns returned use `cursor.getColumnNames()` and just call `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(names[0]))` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userinfo;"
```

return always result with count, it's one row. Replace it by

```
"SELECT * FROM userinfo;"
```

but better way to use

```
Cursor cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userinfo;",null);
int cnt = cursor.getInt(0);
```